# Find a sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, complex-numbers, fibonacci-numbers, closed-form

Find the function for the sequence $a_0 = 0, a_1 = 1$ and $a_{n}=a_{n+10}+a_n$ for all $n>0$.

Comment: Let me know if my edits preserve the same question

Comment: Your first few words seem contradictory: $a$ is a real-valued sequence, yet $a$ maps from the positive integers to the complex plane?

Answer (score 2):

Let's build such function:
$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty F_nx^n,
$$
where $F_n$ are Fibonacci numbers.

Then
$$
f(x) = x+\sum_{n=2}^\infty (F_{n-1}+F_{n-2})x^n = x + \sum_{k=1}^\infty F_kx^{k+1}+\sum_{m=0}^\infty F_mx^{m+2} 
\\= x+xf(x)+x^2f(x),
$$
or much wide:
$$
f(x) = x+x^2+2x^3+3x^4+5x^5+8x^6+13x^7+\cdots \\
= x \;\;+\;\; (x^2+x^3+2x^4+3x^5+5x^6+8x^7+\cdots )\\
\qquad\qquad\quad\;\; +( x^3+x^4+2x^5+3x^6+5x^7+\cdots) \\
=x+xf(x)+x^2f(x),
$$

hence 
$$
(1-x-x^2)f(x)=x,
$$

$$
f(x)=\dfrac{x}{1-x-x^2}.
$$